# Sci-fi movie about alien investigation

Tags: story-identification, movie, aliens, detective

I'm searching for a movie that I saw as a child. The movie is about an investigation for an alien killer. The main character was a male detective who tried to understand what is happening. There was some exotic weapons, what I remember is a razor gun that used by the aliens. The gun shot rotating razor discs that never stopped rotating (and bouncing). The detective found a projectile trapped by a speaker's magnet. The guns used some white fluid in small transparent containers as ammunition.

There is a huge possibility that my memories are not perfect, but the key to find the movie is that razor gun.

Comment: How certain are you that it was a movie?  One of the aliens in **Journeyman Project 3: Legacy of Time** — a video game on the Mac & Windows platforms — used spinning discs as projectiles fired by their guns.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is "[Dark Angel](http://best3d-bluraymovies.blogspot.co.uk/2013/10/dark-angel-1990.html)" from 1990.

The blurb mentions that it's basically a [police procedural but with aliens](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/SpacePolice).

> ***The other alien that has landed on Earth is a lawman and was sent to
>   track the drug dealer. He will need Lundgren's and Benben's help to
>   catch him.*** Throw in the fact that the alien drug dealer takes on drug
>   dealers on Earth and you have non stop action.

This review mentions a strange alien CD-like projectile caught on a speaker magnet

> *This is one of the scariest and funniest movies Dolph Lundgren ever
>   did. I enjoy it immensely and I'm disappointed to see it so expensive
>   and hard to get. I hope a Blu-ray version comes out as this movie did
>   not get the exposure it should have during it's release Christmas of
>   1990. I am kind of surprised so few have heard of this SciFi with aliens coming to Earth. Police detectives Lundgren and Benben try to
>   figure out what exactly they are doing after some drug dealers and
>   civilians are murdered. **At a drug dealers they find several dead
>   bodies and a unusual sharp metal CD stuck to a speaker magnet.** The guy
>   they take it to for analysis at the university looks like he has been
>   drinking Jolt and taking amphetamines. The whole movie has a mix of
>   good SciFi drama and comedy. I had never seen Lundgren in a comedy
>   before and this was a nice change of pace. It reminds me of how
>   "Twins" made a difference in Arnold Scwharzenegger's career. Great
>   quality DVD with plenty of replayability. If you enjoyed this, catch
>   Split Second.*

Comment: Yes, thank you! :)

Comment: @Macros - https://media.giphy.com/media/27HV41s8XXFoQ/giphy.gif

Comment: I saw this in the US as "I Come In Peace", I remember the line between them, Alien: "I come in Peace", Dolph: "The you can go in pieces"  Not a bad movie for the time

Answer (score -1):

I think that the other answer is wrong. I think that an old Mark Hamill movie called "the Guyver" had a spinning blade. Or it might have been in "Krull," I can't really remember. Best bet is to watch all three movies and report back with your findings. To be honest I'm sure they're all friggin' terrible.

[image]

Comment: With the other answer already being acknowledged by the OP, it's not a good idea to say "the other answer is wrong". Change that to "In case other people find this question and that's not it..." to avoid attracting downvotes.

Comment: @MrLister: At tge very least, it would make sense to juxtapose the other answer's film and this one to demonstrate how this one is a better match.